# writing objects of list in a different .csv files using for loop in r

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

HI I want to write objects of list into different csv files, how do i do that
like I want elements of dataFrame "a" to be written into different csv file, elements of dataFrame "b" to be written into different csv file and so on.
any help would be much appreciated
this is what I have tried

```
a = data.frame(1:5)
b = data.frame(c(11,22,33,44,55))
d = data.frame(c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"))
e = data.frame(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))
g = data.frame(c(1,0,1,0,1))
myList <- list(a,b,d,e,g)
myfunction <- function(myList) {
  for(i in 1:myList) {
    write.table(myList[i], file = paste(names(myList), ".csv", sep = "",sep = ",")
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you got several typos in your code. E.g. not closing the bracket after your paste command, etc.

However, the main reason why your code does not work is, because you did not create a named list. **You need to name your list elements, if you want to use names on the list.** Otherwise `names(myList)` will return just `NULL`. Have a look at how `myList` is defined now.

```
a = data.frame(1:5)
b = data.frame(c(11,22,33,44,55))
d = data.frame(c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"))
e = data.frame(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))
g = data.frame(c(1,0,1,0,1))
myList <- list(a=a,b=b,d=d,e=e,g=g)

myfunction <- function(myList) {
  for(i in seq(1,length(myList))) {
  write.table(myList[[i]], file = paste(names(myList)[i], ".csv", sep=""),sep = ",")
  }
}
```

Comment: apologies! I being a novice this type of typos has occur,anyways this is what I expected ..Thanks